# How to use transform with vectors of pairs in c++

Tags: c++, transform

I would like some help on how to use transform on vectors of pairs. I went through the previous answers but did not find what I was looking for. In the code below I divide the first elements of a vector of pairs by a constant and then transfer both the first and second elements to a new vector of pairs. The code works fine but I would like to learn how to use transform along with a lambda function. I was not able to compose a lambda function. Any help from the experts will be most appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void GraphSigm<T,U>::doTransform()
{
    sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    typename std::vector<std::pair<U,U>>::const_iterator it0, it1;
    it0 = v1.begin();
    it1 = v1.end() - 1;
    U maxVal = myMax(fabs((*it0).first), fabs((*it1).first));
    for (auto i : v1) {
        U a = i.first / maxVal;
        U b = i.second;
        v2.push_back(std::make_pair(a, b));
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried? What went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you'd like to transform a vector of `int`'s such that each number is increased by 2.

You can use `std::transform` + lambda function for that:

```
std::vector<int> my_vec = {1,2,3};
std::vector<int> res_vec;
std::transform(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), std::back_inserter(res_vec), [](int x){ return x+2;} );
```

Comment: You might want to capture local variables, i.e. do `[=]` or `[&]` instead of `[]`. This will make the lambda function more useful (e.g. add a value other than 2).

Comment: You might want to `reserve` some capacity on res_vec first. But other than that, I think it's a good answer which shows technique without spoon-feeding OP.

Comment: This is as far as I could go but it does not work; I'm not sure how to deal with modifying the pair:     v2.reserve(v1.size());
    std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2), [&](const std::pair<U, U> &p){ v2.push_back(std::make_pair(p.first/maxVal, log10(p.second)));} );